# fb api request returning a web page but not an object

Tags: javascript, facebook-graph-api

I'm doing something like this:

```
var authToken = "1234";

var album_id = "5678";

var fbAlbum = 'https://graph.facebook.com/' + album_id + '/photos?access_token=' + authToken;
```

But when I check the fbAlbum variable in the debugger it just returns the url that links to all the data that I need.

How can I get the object with all the data?

Comment: You've created the URL, now you have to actually make the request to Facebook's API. For example, try opening that URL in your browser - opening the URL will make the request and return the data. In a similar way, you need your code to actually make the HTTP request to Facebook's servers.

Comment: I recommend that you use [Facebook's supported SDK's](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/javascript) to make requests to their API instead of trying to "reinvent the wheel" and attempting to recreate their behavior.